# ng2 display object in html

Tags: meteor, angular

I'm trying to work out how to display an object in html using angular2.  In ng1 I assigned to a variable and double braced the variable name in the html and bingo!  Now I can't seem to get any data displayed at all.

Here is my simple method call:

```
  onSubmit(value: oSearch): void {
    console.log('you submitted value: ', value);
    Meteor.call('methodName',value.type,value.year,value.idNumber, function(error,result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('failed', error);
      } else {
        this.oResult = result[0];
        console.log('successful call', this.oResult);
      }
    })
  }
```

The object gets printed to the console.  But I cannot get it to render by using:

```
{{oResult}}
```

oResult is declared using

```
oResult:Object;
```

Completely new to ts and ng2.

**Update**

Okay, I tried NgZone, but that didn't work.  I'm getting behaviour I really don't understand.

```
} else {      
console.log('successful call', result[0].topItem);
this.oResult = result[0];
console.log('successful call', this.oResult);
```

Both console.logs print the object correctly but oResult displays as [object Object]

If I change to:

```
this.oResult.topItem = result[0].topItem
```

then I get a Meteor error thrown and the 2nd console.log doesn't print.  The error is:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'methodName': TypeError: Cannot set property 'topItem' of undefined
```

My server method was working perfectly with ng1.  I've tried a synchronous version of http but no change in behaviour has resulted.

Perhaps someone knows of a tutorial demo of http method call using updated angular2-meteor that I can fork?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241724/ng2-update-template-after-making-a-simple-meteor-call

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't recognize the value change if fields are updated by code running outside Angulars zone. Inject `zone: NgZone` and run the code within `zone.run(...)`. It might also be sufficient to initialize the library within Angular to make it use the async API patched by Angular which notifies Angular about possible changes.

```
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  }

  onSubmit(value: oSearch): void {
    console.log('you submitted value: ', value);
    Meteor.call('methodName',value.type,value.year,value.idNumber, function(error,result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('failed', error);
      } else {
        zone.run(function() {
          this.oResult = result[0];
          console.log('successful call', this.oResult);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

See also [Service events do not affect template correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835697/service-events-do-not-affect-template-correctly) for an example.